# android getCurrentPosition() show a some text on special period of time

Tags: android, time, avaudioplayer

I have an audio player in my activity and I want to show some text during audio is playing.
as example I want to show text1 during second 0 to 6 and show text2 during second 6 to 10.

I have timeString:

```
 private String getTimeString(long millis) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        int hours = (int) (millis / (1000*60*60));
        int minutes = (int) (( millis % (1000*60*60) ) / (1000*60));
        int seconds = (int) (( ( millis % (1000*60*60) ) % (1000*60) ) / 1000);

        buf
            .append(String.format("%02d", hours))
            .append(":")
            .append(String.format("%02d", minutes))
            .append(":")
            .append(String.format("%02d", seconds));

        return buf.toString();
    }
```

and I can getCurrentPossition by this:

```
 getTimeString(mp.getCurrentPosition())
```

Comment: so what is output like?

Comment: can u show code where u r trying to show xxx text on x time?

Comment: I don't know the method that should I use!

Comment: can u post complete code?